# how to set a default value in input datepicker

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to set a default value a date picker using JavaScript.

How could I set a default value into the input as actual date for example: **20210706**  because  actually in my form I'm getting 20070620

here is my code and my script to set a pattern is as such

```js
$(function() {
  $('input[name="datetimes"]').daterangepicker({
    singleDatePicker: true,
    locale: {
      format: 'YYYYMMDD'
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/latest/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css" />


<input type="text" class="form-control" id="rangepicker4" name="datetimes" />
```

Comment: I updated  the snippet with the relevant daterangepicker library from CDN

Comment: I see `20210706` today

Comment: 20210706 is next month. yyyymmdd is not reversible as yyyyddmm

Comment: 20210706 is today!

Comment: i need just to add the library you added  ?

Comment: This might seem obvious, but does the PC running this code have the date/time set correctly?

Comment: The [documentation for the library has a configuration generator](http://www.daterangepicker.com/#config) that will produce the code you need...

Comment: it's always showing 20070620

Comment: I get 20210706 - which is correct. I add a value= it sets the starting date
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="rangepicker4" name="datetimes" value="20210708"/> will default 8th July 2021

Comment: do i have to put the library in head section ?

Comment: @ColinRooney when i add value="20210708" it's showing me an error input (Invalid date)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It runs in the snippet here - as did the original post once edited by @mplungjan

```js
$(function() {
  $('input[name="datetimes"]').daterangepicker({
    singleDatePicker: true,
    locale: {
      format: 'YYYYMMDD'
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/latest/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css" />


<input type="text" class="form-control" id="rangepicker4" name="datetimes" value="20210708" />
```